# body_add_img with custom image size

Tags: r, image, jpeg, docx, officer

I want to add images to a serie of docx.files.
But I do not want to change their size - each image has different width and height. How can I specify this for every imagine in:

```
 sample_doc %>% body_add_img(paste0(data_base$Skizze[[x]],".JPG"),width = 5.5, height = 5.5)
```

I would need to get for every image separately height and width to overwrite it. How could I do this?

[image: I know the number of pixels]

[image: But I don't know how Microsoft Word computes the cm width and height for the default insertion - I want that for every document.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read each file with `readJPEG` from `jpeg` and use `dim`:

```
library(jpeg)
img <- readJPEG("pic.jpg")

dim(img)
```

The first two elements are the pixels, the third is always 3 (R, B, G). Now you divide the pixels by 96 and you have the width and height in inch and you can loop through your list of pictures with these values.